# Limit of an integral $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{1385}^{2017}f(nx)\,dx $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

Suppose $f(x)$ is continuous function $$f:[0,+\infty)\mapsto\mathbb{R}$$
and $$\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=1$$
how to find $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{1385}^{2017}f(nx)\,dx $$ 
Honestly, I have no idea for a start. can someone help me? thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems that the expression under the integral sign converges uniformly to some function. Can you guess what this function is?

Comment: @MarvinF This is totally different: $2017\ne2006$. (haha...)

Answer (score 1):

$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 1.$ That means no matter how small $\varepsilon>0$ is, if $x$ is big enough, then $1-\varepsilon < f(x) < 1+\varepsilon.$

So let $n$ be so big that when $1385\le x\le 2017$ then $f(nx)$ is big enough to make that inequality hold. Then you have
$$
\int_{1385}^{2017} (1-\varepsilon) \,dx \le \int_{1385}^{2017} f(nx)\,dx\le \int_{1385}^{2017} (1+\varepsilon)\,dx.
$$
This is true no matter how small $\varepsilon>0$ is.

Answer (score 1):

Set $a:=1385$ and $b:=2017$; it's clear that when $x\in[a,b]=:D$, then $nx\in[na,nb]=:D_n$
$$
M_n:=\max_{x\in D_n} f(x)\;\;\;,\;\;m_n:=\min_{x\in D_n} f(x).
$$
Now by substitution 
$$
\int_a^bf(nx)\,dx=\frac1n\int_{na}^{nb} f(u)\,du.
$$
Then it's clear that
$$
m_n(b-a)
\le m_n\frac1nn(b-a)
\le\frac1n\int_{na}^{nb} f(u)\,du
\le M_n\frac1nn(b-a)
\le M_n(b-a)
$$
Finally, since both $M_n$ and $m_n$ converges to 1, we get the conclusion.